# get all docs from couchDB updated in a specific time range

Tags: couchdb

I would like to get all the docs in couchDb updated in a specific time range.

I'm using the below API but I don't get any result.

/_all_docs?startkey="2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"&endkey="2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"

Any suggestions are welcome.

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

`_all_docs`'s key is the document ID, not timestamp. For your query to be useful, you'll need to create a custom view based on a timestamp (and ensure the timestamp is updated by your code).